# How to use a while-loop in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, while

Though it's not recommended to use a while-loop in GEE, I still need to use one.

I first set a time, and then I want to search some Sentinel-1, Sentinel-2, Landsat, and MODIS images, then I use the union function to merge them. If the union image's area doesn't cover the study area, the time goes back one day. Continue search and merge.

Though the assumption returns 0, the loop statement still run. It never breaks.

```
while (ee.Array(img_area.divide(aoi_area).lt(0.8)).and(ee.Number(start0.difference(ee.Date(ee.List(dt).get(0)),'day')).lte(3))){
    img = com(dt,img,aoi);
    dt = changedt(dt);
    img_area = img.area();
}
```

assumption:determine whether the combined image area exceeds 80% and whether the date of the searched image is within 3 days.

com is the function I defined to merge, changedt is the function to go back the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing server-side and client-side operations. Read up on it [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server). `while` is client-side, and the argument is server-side. On the client-side, a server-side object is always a JSON object, which is truthy. Hence you get an infinite loop.

To convert a server-side object to a client-side object you can call `getInfo()`. It works and is something you can simply append your `while` argument with, but it blocks the whole interface. It's often better to use `evaluate()` instead, but that's asynchronous. So you could for instance rearrange your code to use recursion instead of looping.

You normally want to avoid doing something like this altogether though. It's very slow. It often is possible to come up with a solution not requiring such iterative approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot! very useful!!!!!